# Merge two classes in Orientdb

Tags: mysql, orientdb

I want to merge 2 classes fields into one. I have tried Select from multiple target

```
SELECT EXPAND( $c ) LET $a = ( SELECT FROM E ), $b = ( SELECT FROM V ), $c = UNIONALL( $a, $b )
```

but its not working correct. I want it to work like mysql joins.
Basically it is working but in a wrong way. After executing the query what actually happens is, it bring the result of both classes in different rows. While I need it one row.

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem? I have the same issue

Comment: I also need the answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

try document.merge. see [this thread at google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/orient-database/BpHMZkL6PAg/V9S1FCX9TXsJ)
if you wan't to use the merged document in a query I suggest writing an OFunction in javascript which returnes the merged document.